# text widget gives error in running application

Tags: flutter, text

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2ZN1.png)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PermissionPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const PermissionPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text("data");
  }
}
```

My application, which was working healthy in the morning, is now giving this error. I couldn't find the solution, please help.

I deleted vs code and android studio and reinstalled. I downloaded Flutter again. The problem still continues.

Comment: Can you include coed-snippet

Comment: I added it, but it gives everywhere, not on a special page.

Comment: Kinda strange, can you try `flutter upgrade --force`

Comment: Flutter is already up to date on channel stable
Flutter 3.0.5 • channel stable

Comment: Is is possible you;ve edited the source code and remove Text from it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not related to the source code at least. Because even a newly opened application gives the same error.